# How to create a calculated column in Tibco sportfire based on conditions

Tags: python, sql, spotfire

[please click here to see the data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAfL2.jpg)

In Spotfire, how to create a calculated column that represents the sum total  of values from the "FTE nov"  under the condition that "count Sam" is equal to 1. The sum of values should reflect in each resources name in the same project code.

So the answer value for the calculated column will be 0.9 in each resource name for the first project code and 0.2 under each resource name for the second project code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest thing, since your count SAM flag is either zero or one, would be to calculate a simple weighted sum per Project:

```
Sum([FTE_Nov] * [Count_SAM]) over ([Project])
```

Comment: I'm getting a wrong answers for this expression:(

Comment: It should sums the FTR Nov 2024 values only when Count Sam is 1, and calculation should run separately for different project code! For example, for the 125F project code the sum values respective to the count sam 1 is 0.9 and sum values respective to the count sam 0 is 0.43

Comment: it does sum only when Count Sam is 1, unless in your real data Count Sam is not zero elsewhere but another value. I don't understand when you say it should run separately for each project code. It is calculated with an 'over' expression over Project, so it does that.

Comment: Please share the answer you are getting.